# How to access Homestead mysql database (installed on OSX using virtualbox) from a Windows virtual machine (vmware)

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox, vmware, homestead

Hello I have a homestead instance installed on my mac using virtualbox, and I have a windows 8.1 virtual machine installed using vmware on the same mac. I want to be able to access the homestead mysql database. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was the port, I was entering 33060 but you are suppose to leave it blank.

IP: 192.168.10.10

Username: homestead

Password: secret

port: Leave empty